# Converting a Unix time stamp to Java date

Tags: java, date-format

The code is below:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String logTime = format.format(new Date((format.parse("2013-6-30").getTime()+25*24*3600*1000)));
    String logTime1 = format.format(new Date((format.parse("2013-6-30").getTime()+24*24*3600*1000)));
    System.out.println("logTime:  "+logTime);
    System.out.println("logTime1:  "+logTime1);
```

This is the output:

```
  logTime:  2013-06-05
  logTime1:  2013-07-24
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: I am not sure, what the question ist, but in the first case you multiply by 25, the second time by 24. Why is that?

Comment: I assume he means that adding 24 days is not a problem but adding 25 days is.

Comment: the time by 24 is normal,but when multiply 25,it becomes the wrong date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an overflow.  Try

```
25L * 24*3600*1000
```

so the value is a long.  Your IDE should highlight that what you have will overflow.

[image]

this prints a number which is clearly incorrect.

```
-2134967296
```

---

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
long time = format.parse("2013-6-30").getTime();
String logTime = format.format(new Date(time + 25L * 24 * 3600 * 1000));
String logTime1 = format.format(new Date(time + 24L * 24 * 3600 * 1000));
System.out.println("time + 25d:  " + logTime);
System.out.println("time + 24d:  " + logTime1);
```

prints

```
time + 25d:  2013-07-25
time + 24d:  2013-07-24
```

Comment: Didn't know you worked for jetbrains! ;-) (ps: netbeans does not give any warnings... pfff)

Comment: I use Ecipse,because it's the because IDE of java I think

Comment: Eclipse should compile the code the same as you would get on the command line.  Eclipse may have less warnings, but I don't believe it is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Actually it is the right the result, just not the one you expect.

Comment: An `int` is a 32-bit signed value, if you perform a calculation which is too large for it, only the lower 32-bits are preserved.  This is defined in the JLS as it is how most CPUs behave.  It is how 32=bit `int` behave in C.